# Share Moodle Session with other Web Applications

Tags: java, session, moodle, moodle-api

We are developing a Java based web application which needs to be integrated with Moodle. Moodle is using Active Directory to authenticate the users. For some roles in Moodle (e.g Administrators or Course Creator) there is going to be a redirect link available to Java Web App. Link will be available on the Moodle Dashboard. Is there a way by which we can authenticate users to the web application using Moodle Session?  The Web application expects First Name, Last Name, email and Moodle Role to authenticate a user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) is a standard for single sign on like this, so I would recommend using the Moodle authentication plugin [auth_saml](https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_saml2) to provide a SAML IDP and make your java application authenticate using SAML.